# Add image to bottom corner of MapBox.js map

Tags: image, mapbox, html

I have a MapBox.js map up and running and I would like to add an image to the bottom left corner.  I tried adding in this code: 
`<img src="IMAGE URL" height=100 style=’position:fixed;bottom:0px;left:0px;z-index:999’/>` with my image hosted on Dropbox but it did not appear.  I am using several different TileMill produced layers for this map.  How can I add an image that will always be at the bottom left corner of my map?

Comment: The code for my current map is here: https://github.com/SLUGIS/CalMAPPER/blob/gh-pages/index.html

Comment: I was able to change the position of a legend to the bottom left however my image being used as a legend is not a square so all the extra white space around it is still shown.  I want to add a PNG image so this white space is not part of the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add the image as a [Leaflet control](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.6.1/l-icontrol/), then Leaflet takes care of the z-indexing and positioning.

```
var MyControl = L.Control.extend({
    options: {
      position: 'bottomleft'
    },

    onAdd: function (map) {
      // create the control container with a particular class name
      // ** you can add the image to the div as a background image using css
      var container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'my-custom-control');

      // ... initialize other DOM elements, add listeners, etc.
      return container;
    }
});

map.addControl(new MyControl());
```

And the css:

```
.my-custom-control {
  background-image: url('../images/legend.jpg');
  width:xxpx; /* you will likely need to specify image width and height here */
  height:xxpx;
}
```

Comment: Where would I add this in my code?

Comment: anywhere after you declare your map, so starting line 77 in your example.

Comment: Can the css portion also go in my index.html?  I added the code in at line 77 but the page wouldn't load.

Comment: css can go in index, as an inline style (don't forget to change the url to point to wherever your image is). What errors are you getting on the console (F12)?

Comment: if you want to put up a fiddle, or just chat directly about this, I'm sure we could fix it quickly

Comment: Here is a fiddle of my code : http://jsfiddle.net/x1w7wdh7/

Comment: I wasn't able to get the fiddle working (yours or my fork), but with a couple of small changes I did have this running straight off my desktop. All you need to do is 1) delete line 93 ("And the css") - this is just a comment; 2) move the css that follows (lines 95-99) up into one of the <style> tags (69 for example); 3) finally, change that css to this: `.my-custom-control { background: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/345322813/logos/Div6Logo_PNG_original.png'); background-size: 100px 100px; width: 100px; height: 100px; }`

Comment: the line numbers here refer to the fiddle, not the file in your earlier link

Comment: That did the trick!